# What is a PostgreSQL query that will run slowly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to test some things and I need a PostgreSQL query that will run rather slow (lasting .01 to 10 seconds) so that I can check that my handling of asynchronous requests is correct. I also need that query to return a result if possible.

At first I started populating the database with thousands of records, but there must be a better way that provides more control over how long the query should run.

Comment: SELECT pg_sleep(60); SELECT 1; http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @raspi: uhm, why do you think so?

Comment: @raspi: PostgreSQL does not have a dual table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah but you can make one in 5 seconds

Comment: @Bohemian: true, but raspi's statement would still not qualify as "long running". Multiplying two numbers and returning a single row will finish in milliseconds

Comment: Time is not an absolute measure. The "probe" query will compete with the current "ecosystem" of queries for every possible resource. (locks, bufferspace, memory, CPU, catalogs) First: choose *what* you want to measure. Responsiveness? Contention? Throughput?

Comment: @Bohemian: Also, why would anybody want to introduce Oracle's silly crutch (DUAL) into PostgreSQL where it is not needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pg_sleep(seconds)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY)

```
SELECT pg_sleep(1.5);  -- pauses 1.5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

If pg_sleep doesn't do what you need, cross products usually do a nice job on slowing things down. Find a table with a good number of rows, multiply by itself as many times as you need, and do something with the set.

```
select count(*)
  from pg_tables a
      ,pg_tables b
      ,pg_tables c
      ,pg_tables d
```